# overlaping issues between nodes and slpit condition while ploting decission tree using rpart.plot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, rpart

I am trying to make a decision tree using rpart package in R programming. So when i print the decision tree using rpart.plot package, the splitting rule and the node both are overlaping which looks the tree weird. Any suggestions on which parameters to pass in rpart.plot () so that I can generate an extra space between the node and the splitting rule.Thank you.[This image is generated by below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT7a4.png)

Below is code I tried in r programming.

```
rpart.plot(tree1, type = 4, 
           extra = 101, under = TRUE, 
           cex = 0.8, box.palette = "auto",
           varlen = 4,faclen = 4,
           fallen.leaves = TRUE)
```